# OnFlowDirection change for a FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I created this custom control named Cflowcontrol and I need to know when the FlowDirection of this control changes

So this is what I did:

```
Inherits FlowLayoutPanel
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Private Fdirection As FlowDirection
Public Event FDirectionChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal info As String)
    RaiseEvent FDirectionChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
End Sub
Shadows Property FlowDirection As FlowDirection
    Get
        Return Fdirection
    End Get
    Set(value As FlowDirection)
        If value <> Fdirection Then
            Fdirection = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("FlowDirection")
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

So far so good it tells me when the property changes it value
the problem is that the flowdirection of the controls within the panel doesn't change anymore

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the base control to update itself:

```
Protected Sub OnNotifyPropertyChanged(info As String)
  RaiseEvent FDirectionChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
End Sub

Shadows Property FlowDirection As FlowDirection
  Get
    Return MyBase.FlowDirection
  End Get
  Set(value As FlowDirection)
    If value <> MyBase.FlowDirection Then
      MyBase.FlowDirection = value
      OnNotifyPropertyChanged("FlowDirection")
    End If
  End Set
End Property
```